# how to create a regular expression to validate the numbers are not same even separated by hyphen (-) or Alpha Numeric

Tags: java, regex

Requirement is : Field is made of 1 alpha character followed by 15 alpha numeric characters including maximum 2 hyphens (-)

Regex:`^(?!^(.)\\1*$)([A-Z]{1}(?=[A-Z0-9-]{2,15}$)[A-Z0-9]*(?:\\-[A-Z0-9]*){0,2}[A-Z0-9]+$)`

Above Regex is working fine but as the requirement it's not allowed the duplicate numbers like `1) N000000000000000  2)N000000-0000-0`

the above 2 values not to allow as its has the same digit as "0".

Comment: Just to clarify: you tried `(?!^(.)\1*$)` to solve this, right?

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[A-Z](?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)+\D*$)(?=.{2,15}$)[A-Z0-9]*(?:-[A-Z0-9]*){0,2}[A-Z0-9]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DCMZmn/1). Inside the code, in your string literals, make sure you escape backslashes twice.

*Details*:

- `^`  - start of string
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)+\D*$)` - the string cannot contain only identical digits
- `(?=.{2,15}$)` - there must be 2 to 15 chars other than line break chars to the right of the current position
- `[A-Z0-9]*` - zero or more ASCII uppercase letters/digits
- `(?:-[A-Z0-9]*){0,2}` - zero, one or two occurrences of `-` and then zero or more ASCII uppercas eletters/digits
- `[A-Z0-9]+` - one or more ASCII uppercase letters/digits
- `$` - end of string.
  `

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribizew . Can you please help similar req ex it's not allowed even Same Alphabet as well? like NNNNN its not allowed but NNN1 allowed.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy Replace `(?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)+\D*$)` with `(?!\W*(\w)(?:\W*\1)+\W*$)`

Comment: Yes working but one case its not working the first character is not considering ex ABBB is valid but its not allow because from second character its same. Regex ^[A-Z](?!\W*(\w)(?:\W*\1)+\W*$)(?=.{2,15}$)[A-Z0-9]*(?:-[A-Z0-9]*){0,2}[A-Z0-9]+$

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribizew, Can you share the reference materials or books to learn the regex concepts.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy for the letter check, sure, you should move the lookahead to `^`: `^(?!\W*(\w)(?:\W*\1)+\W*$)[A-Z](?=.{2,15}$)[A-Z0-9]*(?:-[A-Z0-9]*){0,2}[A-Z0-9]+$`.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy I can suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at. You are welcome to check my profile page for a link to my RegexQuickies YT channel.